# What's the power series solution of $y' = x^2\,y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My attempted solution

[image]

I'm not sure how to factor out $x$. In the other problems I've solved, both series terms have the same power of $x$. but in this problem one series contains $x^{n+2}$ and the other contains $x^n$.

Comment: That's just syntactic sugar. The real point here is this: what is the (combined) coefficient of $x^0$? What is the coefficient of $x^1$? Of $x^2, x^3$ and $x^4$? The $\sum$ notation lets you be a bit more compact about it, but don't forget that it is nothing more than shorthand.

If you can't see how to add them directly, then write them out, add them term by term, then see if maybe you can't combine the result back into a $\sum$ expression afterwards. Hopefully, in the process, you spot the quick way so you can do that the next time.

Comment: Next time please cut the picture. BTW since you are new here take a few moments for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Make a *change of variable* in the summation index. For instance, letting $n+2=k$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{(n+2)}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_{k-2}x^k.
$$